# When "get" in the properties (C#) is able to return a single instance?

Tags: c#

From time to time I  find a code like this:

```
 private Foo _myfoo;  
 public Foo MyFoo
            {
                get { return _myfoo ??  new Foo();  }
                private set {_myfoo = value;}
            }
```

Does it mean that when _myfoo  is not set, MyFoo  return a **non** single instance of Foo (i.e. get does new Foo() always)?
What can I do MyFoo'd return single instance of Foo? 
_myfoo can be set through a constructor of the class, for example, any variants?

Comment: Looks to me like, if _myinstance is not initialized by a call to the setter prior to calling the getter, the getter will return null.

Comment: Sure looks that way. Without seeing the rest of the code, I can't say for sure, but I'd think that a `get` method with a backing variable like that should look like: `{ if ( _myInstance == null ) _myInstance = new Foo(); return _myInstance; }`

Comment: `get { if (_myinstance == null) { _myinstance = new Foo(); } return _myinstance; }`

Comment: get { return _myinstance == null ? new Foo() : _myinstance; } Of courst, this doesn't set _myinstance to a new Foo, just returns one if _myinstance is null.

Comment: @Kevin Your comment is essentially the same exact routine he posted in the question - it will never actually instantiate _myinstance and will always return a new instance of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assumption is correct. From the code we can see, it'll create a new instance of `Foo` every time you try to get the value.

There are multiple ways you could set that instance variable, such as through the constructor (as you suggested), or "set" it the first time you "get" the value.

Here's another one. It'll create a new `Foo` the first time, and assign it to `_myinstance`, so that it doesn't create another instance on subsequent `get`'s.

```
get { return _myinstance = (_myinstance ?? new Foo()); }
```

Comment: @Grant Winney , it's very helpful for me, thank)
That code, which I wrote above, is wrong, as I can think

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net 4.0 (or later), you can use the Lazy<> class to create an instance on first use.

[Lazy(T) Class MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 private Lazy<Foo> _myfoo = new Lazy<Foo>();  
 public Foo MyFoo
 {
   get { return _myfoo.Value; }
 }
```